# MySQL: debug failed deletion with FK contraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

How do i debug a deletion of mysql when the deletion fails because of a foreign key constraint?

**Example:**

I execute a statement:

```
DELETE FROM SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A WHERE id=1;
```

and get the error:

```
ERROR 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SCHEMA_A`.`TABLE_B`, CONSTRAINT `FK123` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `TABLE_C` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Now, as you can see, there is an "ON DELETE CASCADE" for the constraint and therefore this issue seems to include something more than just the constraint. Furthermore, i do not directly delete from TABLE_C.

Therefore, my question above is related to finding the real cause of such an error. For example, it would be helpful to get something like a "dependency graph" / "stack trace" of the deletion path (e.g. TABLE_A FKxy causes the deletion of entries of TABLE_Y with FKz causes the deletion of entries from TABLE_C) or which rows are actually tried to delete.

Comment: Just for the record: the problem here was the depth limitation (depth <= 15) of the "ON DELETE CASCADE" DFS resolution on innodb tables. However, I am still interested on how to get a solution for my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check the foreign keys using this statement

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = '<table>';
```

Comment: it is a filtered display of the direct constraints as proposed by @Anjan. still it does now show me, why the deletion is done in the above situation, because TABLE_A does not have a direct constraint to TABLE_B or TABLE_C.